# Build VTK with Python Bindings and CUDA, TBB, & MPI on Windows

Tags: python, vtk, cmake-gui

#### Problem

I cannot load `VTK` into `python` on `Windows` with support for `CUDA`, `MPI`, and `TBB`. Volume rendering is unreasonably slow for production with the default PyPI distribution (hours or more) and I need to leverage my hardware to speed up computations.

I have successfully built `VTK 9.3.0` for `Python 3.8.10-x64` with `CMake` and `Visual Studio` and have `bin`, `lib`, `include`, and `share` folders and have added these to `PATH`, but Python does not see `vtk`:

```
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtk'
>>>
```

I attempted to place the generated `Lib/site-packages`, `bin`, `lib`, and `include` folders in appropriate places in `C:\Program Files\Python38`, but I still get a `DLL` load error:

```
> py -3.8
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import vtkCommonCore
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing vtkCommonCore: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\vtk.py", line 30, in <module>
    all_m = importlib.import_module('vtkmodules.all')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import _vtkmodules_static
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_vtkmodules_static'
>>>
```

#### Setup

---

**OS:** Windows 10 Enterprise, x64-bit, Build 1909
**CPU:** 2x Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6248R
**Disk:** 2TB NVMe M.2 SSD
**RAM:** 192 GB DDR4
**Compute GPUs:** 2x NVIDIA Quadro RTX8000 in TCC mode with NVLink
**Display GPU:** 1x NVIDIA Quadro RTX4000
**Visual Studio:** [Visual Studio 16 2019 Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/)
**Windows SDK:** [10.0.19041.0](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/), targeting 10.0.18363
**Python:** [3.8.10 x64-bit](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3810/)
**CMake:** [3.21.1](https://cmake.org/) (*I use `CMake-GUI`*)
**vcpkg:** [2021-08-12](https://vcpkg.io/en/index.html)
**VTK Source:** [vtk-9.0.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64](https://vtk.org/download/)  (download from VTK website; not GitHub master)
**VTKPythonPackage:** [GitHub Link](https://github.com/KitwareMedical/VTKPythonPackage)  (*...not sure if I need this...*)
**CUDA Toolkit:** [11.4](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit)
**TBB:** [2021.3.0](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/all-toolkits.html#base-kit)  (via Intel(R) oneAPI Base Toolkit)
**MPI:** [2021.3.0](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/all-toolkits.html#base-kit)  (via Intel(R) oneAPI HPC Toolkit)

---

**NOTE:**  *If desired, Embree, OSPRay, and OpenVKL are available in the Intel(R) oneAPI Rendering Toolkit*

#### Preparation

---

***NOTE:*** *There are **A LOT** of programs to be downloaded, installed, and configured, and they are important for proper building. In an attempt to shorten this post to an MRE (Minimal Reproducable Example), please go straight to the `Steps to Reproduce` section.*

***NOTE:*** *When setting Environment Variables, you may get an error that a PATH length greater than 2047 is not permitted. To overcome this hurdle, it is simplest to edit the path directly in the Windows Registry. Open `regedit` as an Admin, navigate to*

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

*and set the `Path` variable there.*

***TIP:*** *To edit `PATH`, I copy and paste from the Registry into Word, then selected and replace `;`'s with paragraph endings `^p` by selecting `Ctrl+H` and then using the `Replace` tool as follows:*

[image: Find and Replace]

*When finished, I simply reverse the changes by replacing `^p`'s with `;`s. This is simpler for me than struggling with regular expressions.*

---

##### 1. Install Visual Studio

1. Download the [Visual Studio Installer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/)
2. Run the installer, choose `Visual Studio Community 2019`, and select `Desktop development with C++`. Ensure the following are selected in `Individual Components`

- `Windows 10 SDK`
- `C++ ATL for latest...`
- `C++ MFC for latest...`
- `C++ CMake tools for Windows`

***NOTE:*** (For me on `Windows 10` with `Visual Studio 2019`, these are `v142`)

3. Ensure the path to the corresponding `bin`, `lib`, and `include` folders are in the `PATH` of `System Environment Variables`. These can  be either:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include
```

and/or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include
```

***NOTE:*** (I recommend the latter at a minimum. )

4. Ensure the following additional `System Environment Variables` have been set by the installer:

```
VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\
VS160COMCOMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\
VS2019INSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
VSSDK140INSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VSSDK\
```

***NOTE:*** *Even though the installer downloads these to `Program Files (x86)`, they are in fact the `x64-bit` programs (I know...Windows is weird...)*

##### 2. Install CUDA

1. Download and run `cuda_11.4.1_471.41_win10.exe` ([link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-4-0-download-archive?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exe_local))

***TIP:*** *The local installer will take longer to download, but your installs will run faster. I recommend saving the installer for the future anyway in case your CUDA Toolkit becomes corrupted or you need to install on another machine.*

2. Ensure the following are added to `PATH` in `System Environment Variables`

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4\bin
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4\libnvvp
```

***ASIDE:*** *You **MUST** use version 11.4 for `VTK 9`. However, as an aside, when using 10.2 in CMake, if CMake cannot find CUDA, this is probably because the CUDA Toolkit 10.2 installer for some reason does not copy the `Visual Studio MSBuild Extensions` over to your Visual Studio folder. Copy the files at*

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\extras\visual_studio_integration\MSBuildExtensions\
```

*to*

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\BuildCustomizations
```

***NOTE:*** *If you want to run your GPU in TCC mode (**WARNING:** This disables graphics output), and/or if you have two GPUs connected via NVLink and want to activate NVLink, run the following command in command prompt:*

```
> nvidia-smi -i 0 -dm 1
> nvidia-smi -i 1 -dm 1
```

*Assuming you have two GPUs with ID's 0 and 1 you want to run in TCC mode. (To check, simply run `nvidia-smi` and see which GPUs you want to activate in TCC mode with the `-dm` switch). The [PugetSystems Instructions](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/support-hardware/How-to-Enable-and-Test-NVIDIA-NVLink-on-Quadro-and-GeForce-RTX-Cards-in-Windows-10-1266/) have change with CUDA 11. NVIDIA's newer drivers, which ship with the NVIDIA Control Panel, no longer have the `Configure SLI, Surround, PhysX` under `3D Settings`, particularly if using a Quadro card rather than a GeForce card. Instead, NVLink will be activated once TCC mode is set, which disables graphics output. The program they have provided only works for CUDA 10, so you will get an error with it when using CUDA 11 even though it is enabled.*

***NOTE:*** *If you get an error "Intel Graphics Driver for Windows not found", ignore it. You only need the drivers for the CPU.*

***NOTE:*** *Don't add more than the `/lib/` and `/libnvvp/` folders to path. CMake might not be able to find CUDA if you do. If you have to add other folders (e.g. `CUPTI`), I recommend the `lib/` and `libnvvp/` folder appear **FIRST** in PATH.*

##### 3. Install `CMake`

1. Download and install [CMake](https://cmake.org/)  (...that was easy)

##### 4. Install `vcpkg`

1. Download and configure `vcpkg`:

```sh
cd C:\
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
cd vcpkg
.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
vcpkg integrate install
```

2. Set the default triplet in the `System Environment Variables` to `x64-windows`:

```
VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET=x64-windows
```

3. Install ports using `vcpkg install`. Press `Configure` in CMake and every time it cannot find a dependency you want installed, search for the dependency with `vcpkg search` and install it with `vcpkg install` (to remove a package, use `vcpkg remove`)._

***NOTE:*** ***BE AWARE** that depending on what you install, these dependencies take **A LOT** of space and take **A LONG TIME** to download.*

##### 5. Install `Intel oneAPI Toolkits`

***NOTE:*** *These include `TBB`, `MPI`, `OSPRay`, and the Intel Fortran compiler `ifort.exe`, which you need.*

1. Intel(R) oneAPI Base Toolkit
2. Intel(R) oneAPI HPC Toolkit
3. Intel(R) oneAPI Rendering Toolkit (*for Embree, OSPRay, and OpenVKL, optionally*)

and add the corresponding `lib`, `bin`, and `include` folders to `PATH`.

##### 6. Install `Intel SPMD Compiler`

1. [Intel(R) Implicit SPMD Program Compiler](https://ispc.github.io/downloads.html)

##### 7. Additional Dependencies with Installers

***NOTE:*** *You may not need or want need these. I am adding them here for completeness. If CMake complains about not finding these, I recommend installing them.*

1. [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Download)
2. [WiX Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/)
3. [MySQL Community (GPL) Installer for Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)
4. [MySQL ODBC Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)
5. [Strawberry Perl](https://strawberryperl.com/)

##### 8. Dependencies that are Unsuccessful on Windows

***NOTE:*** *I have tried installing binaries for these and adding them to `PATH`, but they just don't seem to work on Windows..*

***NOTE:*** *For each of these, you can also try downloading corresponding python 3.8 zip source file (on `GitHub, under` Releases`, and on` conda forge`, under` Files`) to a folder on` C:` and then add the subfolders `bin`, `lib`, `include` (and `share` if available) to the `PATH` `System Environment Variable`.*

1. [OpenTurns 1.17](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/openturns/files)
2. [GDAL 3.3.1](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal/files)

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. I set my `PATH` first. `VTK` will make `bin`, `include`, `lib`, and `share` folders, so I make sure these are at the front of `PATH`. Here is what I have (***HINT:*** Refer to setting `PATH` in `regedit` to avoid the Windows error of PATH length greater than 2047 characters in the Preparation section above)
2. Open an `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019` terminal as an Administrator and run

```
> cmake-gui
```

This ensures `vcvarsall.bat` is run and the corresponding Environment Variables it sets are passed on to `CMake-GUI`.

3. Set the Source folder to `C:\VTK\src` and Build folder to `C:\VTK`

---

#### UPDATE 27-AUG-2021:

***Step 3 was the problem. The build folder was previously `C:\VTK\build`. It needed to be `C:\VTK`. I corrected this.***

---

4. Press `Configure` and select `Visual Studio 16 2019` as the generator with `x64` as the optional platform:
   [image: CMake01]

**NOTE:** *I do not know if libraries for VTK and CUDA should be built for 32-bit. I am using 64-bit as my best guess.*

5. After Configuration completes, you will see many variables, which is understandably overwhelming and it is unclear what the differences are between `DEFAULT`, `YES`, `NO`, `WANT`, and `DON'T WANT`. Unfortunately, the answer is hidden tucked away in VTK's CMake Module API Doxygen docs

[VTK CMake Module API](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/group__module.html)

[image: Enable Status Values]

For now, I leave everything default and edit the following CMake variables:

***TIP:*** *Check the `Grouped` and `Advanced` check boxes next to the `Add Entry` button to see all variables grouped by corresponding project/module:*

```
CMAKE_CXX_MP_FLAG    Checked
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX    C:/VTK
VTK_GROUP_ENABLE_Imaging    WANT
VTK_GROUP_ENABLE_MPI    WANT
VTK_GROUP_ENABLE_Qt    WANT
VTK_PYTHON_VERSION    3
VTK_SMP_IMPLEMENTATION_TYPE    TBB
VTK_USE_CUDA    Checked
VTK_USE_MPI    Checked
VTK_WRAP_PYTHON    Checked
VTK_ENABLE_KITS    Checked
```

and delete

```
Python2_EXECUTABLE
```

under `Ungrouped Entries`

6. Rerun Configure
7. Change the following CMake Variables:

```
Python3_EXECUTABLE    C:/Program Files/Python38/python.exe
Python3_INCLUDE_DIR    C:/Program Files/Python38/include
Python3_LIBRARY    C:/Program Files/Python38/libs/python38.lib
```

8. Rerun Configure

###### Output from 3rd Configure:

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
Found Python3: C:/Program Files/Python38/python.exe (found suitable version "3.8.10", minimum required is "3.2") found components: Interpreter Development.Module Development.Embed 
Configuring done
```

9. My CMake variables now look like this:

***ASIDE:*** *Would be nice if the CMake GUI had an option to output variables to a text file, especially for debugging...*

***ASIDE:*** *Would be nice if CMake GUI could tell you what had actually been activiated/used since everything shows up with `DEFAULT` value and we don't want to change that...*

***ASIDE:*** *Would be nice if there was a high level overview somewhere of what all of these modules entail so users can understand what they want/need...*

[image: CMake Variables 01]

[image: CMake Variables 02]

[image: CMake Variables 03]

[image: CMake Varables 04]

[image: CMake Variables 05]

[image: CMake Variables 06]

[image: CMake Variables 07]

10. Click `Generate`

###### Output from Generate

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
Configuring done
Generating done
```

11. Open `Visual Studio 2019` as an Administrator
12. Open the Solution file `VTK.sln` in `C:\VTK\build`
13. Change the build type from `Debug` to `Release` for speed:

[image: Release Mode]

14. Right-click on `ALL_BUILD` and select `Build`. In the end, the output is

```
========== Build: 398 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

15. Right-click on `INSTALL` and select `Build`. In the end, the output is:

```
========== Build: 116 succeeded, 0 failed, 283 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

#### Issue

Please see problem at top of post.

#### Update: 26-AUG-2021

Per @JensMunk suggestion, I copied the `VTK` master branch source code to overwrite `vtkmodules/__init__.py` with support for `os.add_dll_directory()`, but to no avail:

```py
r"""
Currently, this package is experimental and may change in the future.
"""
from __future__ import absolute_import

import sys


def _windows_dll_path():
    import os

    _vtk_python_path = 'Lib/site-packages/vtkmodules'
    _vtk_dll_path = 'bin'
    # Compute the DLL path based on the location of the file and traversing up
    # the installation prefix to append the DLL path.
    _vtk_dll_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    # Loop while we have components to remove.
    print("Folder Search:")
    print("==============")
    while _vtk_python_path not in ("", ".", "/"):
        # Strip a directory away.
        _vtk_python_path = os.path.dirname(_vtk_python_path)
        _vtk_dll_directory = os.path.dirname(_vtk_dll_directory)
        if _vtk_python_path != "C:\\":
            print(_vtk_python_path)
    print("==============")
    print()
    _vtk_dll_directory = os.path.join(_vtk_dll_directory, _vtk_dll_path)
    print(f"VTK DLL Directory: {_vtk_dll_directory}")
    print()
    print("Adding DLLs...")
    if os.path.exists(_vtk_dll_directory):
        # We never remove this path; it is required for VTK to work and there's
        # no scope where we can easily remove the directory again.
        print(f"DLL: {_vtk_dll_directory}")
        _ = os.add_dll_directory(_vtk_dll_directory)

    print()
    print("Build tree...")
    # Build tree support.
    try:
        from . import _build_paths

        # Add any paths needed for the build tree.
        for path in _build_paths.paths:
            if os.path.exists(path):
                print(f"Path: {path}")
                _ = os.add_dll_directory(path)
    except ImportError:
        # Relocatable install tree (or non-Windows).
        print("Passing: Relocatable install tree")
        pass
    print()
    print("Imported!")


# CPython 3.8 added behaviors which modified the DLL search path on Windows to
# only search "blessed" paths. When importing SMTK, ensure that SMTK's DLLs are
# in this set of "blessed" paths.
if sys.version_info >= (3, 8) and sys.platform == "win32":
    _windows_dll_path()


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# this little trick is for static builds of VTK. In such builds, if
# the user imports this Python package in a non-statically linked Python
# interpreter i.e. not of the of the VTK-python executables, then we import the
# static components importer module.
try:
    from . import vtkCommonCore
except ImportError:
    import _vtkmodules_static

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# get the version
__version__ = "9.0.3"
```

Attempting to import again, I get the same error, so DLLs are still missing:

```
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
Folder Search:
==============
Lib/site-packages
Lib

==============

VTK DLL Directory: C:\Program Files\Python38\bin

Adding DLLs...
DLL: C:\Program Files\Python38\bin

Build tree...
Passing: Relocatable install tree

Imported!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from . import vtkCommonCore
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing vtkCommonCore: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\vtk.py", line 30, in <module>
    all_m = importlib.import_module('vtkmodules.all')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
    import _vtkmodules_static
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_vtkmodules_static'
```

Comment: From Python 3.8 and onwards, you need to use `os.add_dll_directory` to allow python to load DLLs from a given directory. You need to add the directories containing the VTK DLL and all other DLLs used, Qt, CUDA, MPI etc. It is not enough to add the folders to the PATH

Comment: Volume rendering and CUDA are not related.

Comment: @MathieuWestphal CUDA aside, would `VTK`'s volume rendering be improved by building with support for parallelization?

Comment: @MathieuWestphal Also, I think it might be more appropriate to say they are not related "for `VTK`" (I know it uses/prefers OpenGL). However, there are many applications of volume rendering using CUDA. You can find them with a quick Google search.

Comment: @JensMunk Can you please add example instructions on the `VTK` website and/or GitLab page that shows how to do this?

Comment: @A.Hendry It is not a VTK thing - it is a Python thing. From Python 3.8 and onwards, you need to use `os.add_dll_directory` to allow DLLs to be loaded. They have taken care of this in VTK for Qt and VTK DLLs, but the errors you are seeing may be related to some of the other DLLs that you setup needs. Just a thought

Comment: @JensMunk Even with the fix I made, the DLLs are still unable to load. Can you make any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was putting my generated CMake files into `C:\VTK\build\` and then compiling and installing in `C:\VTK`, which is why Python couldn't find the DLLs. I have corrected the corresponding step in my post so the install instructions are complete and correct.

See section `Steps to Reproduce`, step `3`

Answer (score 0):

#### Update: 26-AUG-2021 (Continued...)

**NOTE:** *This is **NOT** an answer.*

Pretty much doing the exact same thing, but in `vtk.py` instead, plus including all other system dependencies, using `os.add_dll_directory()` does not work:

```
"""This is the vtk module."""

import sys

if sys.version_info < (3, 5):
    # imp is deprecated in 3.4
    import imp
    import importlib

    # import vtkmodules package.
    vtkmodules_m = importlib.import_module("vtkmodules")

    # import vtkmodules.all
    all_m = importlib.import_module("vtkmodules.all")

    # create a clone of the `vtkmodules.all` module.
    vtk_m = imp.new_module(__name__)
    for key in dir(all_m):
        if not hasattr(vtk_m, key):
            setattr(vtk_m, key, getattr(all_m, key))

    # make the clone of `vtkmodules.all` act as a package at the same location
    # as vtkmodules. This ensures that importing modules from within the vtkmodules package
    # continues to work.
    vtk_m.__path__ = vtkmodules_m.__path__
    # replace old `vtk` module with this new package.
    sys.modules[__name__] = vtk_m

else:
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
        import os

        if os.name == "nt":
            WIN_DLLS = set([r"C:\WINDOWS\System32\downlevel"])

            PY_ROOT = sys.exec_prefix
            PY_DLLS = set(
                [
                    os.path.join(PY_ROOT, "DLLs"),
                ]
            )

            try:
                VTK_DIR = os.environ["VTK_DIR"]
            except KeyError:
                VTK_DIR = None

            VTK_DLLS = set([])
            if VTK_DIR is not None:
                # Assumes default folder "bin" used in CMake configuration
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(VTK_DIR, "bin")):
                    for file_ in files:
                        if file_.lower().endswith(".dll") or file_.lower().endswith(
                            ".pyd"
                        ):
                            if root not in VTK_DLLS:
                                VTK_DLLS.add(root)
                            break

            try:
                VULKAN_PATH = os.environ["VK_SDK_PATH"]
            except KeyError:
                VULKAN_PATH = None

            VULKAN_DLLS = set([])
            if VULKAN_PATH is not None:
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(VULKAN_PATH):
                    for file_ in files:
                        if file_.lower().endswith(".dll"):
                            if root not in VULKAN_DLLS:
                                VULKAN_DLLS.add(root)
                            break

            try:
                CUDA_PATH = os.environ["CUDA_PATH"]
            except KeyError:
                CUDA_PATH = None

            CUDA_DLLS = set([])
            if CUDA_PATH is not None:
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(CUDA_PATH):
                    for file_ in files:
                        if file_.lower().endswith(".dll"):
                            if root not in CUDA_DLLS:
                                CUDA_DLLS.add(root)
                            break

            try:
                ONEAPI_ROOT = os.environ["ONEAPI_ROOT"]
            except KeyError:
                ONEAPI_ROOT = None

            ONEAPI_DLLS = set([])
            if ONEAPI_ROOT is not None:
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(CUDA_PATH):
                    for file_ in files:
                        if file_.lower().endswith(".dll"):
                            if root not in ONEAPI_DLLS:
                                ONEAPI_DLLS.add(root)
                            break

            try:
                ISPC_EXECUTABLE = os.environ["ISPC_EXECUTABLE"]
            except KeyError:
                ISPC_EXECUTABLE = None

            ISPC_DLLS = set([])
            if ISPC_EXECUTABLE is not None:
                ISPC_DLLS.add(os.path.dirname(ISPC_EXECUTABLE))

            # INCLUDE = os.path.join(PY_ROOT, "include")
            # LIB = os.path.join(PY_ROOT, "Lib")
            # SITEPACKAGES = os.path.join(PY_ROOT, "Lib", "site-packages")
            # LIBS = os.path.join(PY_ROOT, "libs")
            # SCRIPTS = os.path.join(PY_ROOT, "Scripts")

            dll_directories = [
                WIN_DLLS,
                PY_DLLS,
                VTK_DLLS,
                VULKAN_DLLS,
                CUDA_DLLS,
                ONEAPI_DLLS,
                ISPC_DLLS,
            ]

            print(f"WIN_DLLS: {WIN_DLLS}")
            print(f"PY_DLLS: {PY_DLLS}")
            print(f"VTK_DLLS: {VTK_DLLS}")
            print(f"VULKAN_DLLS: {VULKAN_DLLS}")
            print(f"CUDA_DLLS: {CUDA_DLLS}")
            print(f"ONEAPI_DLLS: {ONEAPI_DLLS}")
            print(f"ISPC_DLLS: {ISPC_DLLS}")

            for dll in dll_directories:
                if dll is not None:
                    for dll_ in dll:
                        os.add_dll_directory(dll_)

    import importlib

    # import vtkmodules.all
    all_m = importlib.import_module("vtkmodules.all")

    # import vtkmodules
    vtkmodules_m = importlib.import_module("vtkmodules")

    # make vtkmodules.all act as the vtkmodules package to support importing
    # other modules from vtkmodules package via `vtk`.
    all_m.__path__ = vtkmodules_m.__path__

    # replace old `vtk` module with the `all` package.
    sys.modules[__name__] = all_m
```

gives output

```
❯ py
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
WIN_DLLS: {'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\downlevel'}
PY_DLLS: {'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\DLLs'}
VTK_DLLS: {'C:\\VTK\\bin\\Lib\\site-packages\\mpi4py', 'C:\\VTK\\bin', 'C:\\VTK\\bin\\Lib\\site-packages\\vtkmodules'}
VULKAN_DLLS: {'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Tools', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Tools32\\styles', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Third-Party\\Bin32', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Tools\\styles', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Tools32\\iconengines', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Tools\\imageformats', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Tools\\platforms', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Tools32\\bearer', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Bin32', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Tools\\bearer', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Bin', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Third-Party\\Bin', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Tools32', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Tools32\\imageformats', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Tools\\iconengines', 'C:\\VulkanSDK\\1.2.182.0\\Tools32\\platforms'}
CUDA_DLLS: {'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.4\\extras\\visual_studio_integration\\MSBuildExtensions', 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.4\\extras\\demo_suite', 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.4\\extras\\CUPTI\\lib64', 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.4\\nvvm\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.4\\compute-sanitizer', 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.4\\libnvvp\\plugins\\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326', 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.4\\bin'}
ONEAPI_DLLS: {'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.4\\extras\\visual_studio_integration\\MSBuildExtensions', 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.4\\extras\\demo_suite', 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.4\\extras\\CUPTI\\lib64', 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.4\\nvvm\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.4\\compute-sanitizer', 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.4\\libnvvp\\plugins\\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326', 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.4\\bin'}
ISPC_DLLS: {'C:\\Program Files\\ISPC\\ispc-v1.16.1-windows\\bin'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import vtkCommonCore
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing vtkCommonCore: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\vtk.py", line 143, in <module>
    all_m = importlib.import_module("vtkmodules.all")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import _vtkmodules_static
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_vtkmodules_static'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also not an answer - but a short recipe for what worked for me.

I use Python 3.8.8 from python.org - should not make any difference.

I use VTK-9.0.1 - before they attempted to fix the `os.add_dll_directory` issue.

I use Qt5.15.2

I am not using vcpkg

1. Make sure the right DLLs are found

```
In [1]: import sys
In [2]: sys.path.insert(0, "c:/{VTK_BUILD_DIR}/bin/Lib/site-packages/")
```

2. Make sure that they are loaded and no errors occur (some are silent)

```
In [5]: import os
In [6]: os.add_dll_directory("c:/{VTK_BUILD_DIR}/bin/Lib/site-packages/vtkmodules/")
In [7]: os.add_dll_directory("c:/{VTK_BUILD_DIR}/bin/Release/")
In [8]: os.add_dll_directory("c:/QT/Qt5.15/5.15.2/msvc2019_64/bin/")

This is made on top of an empty virtual environment, where only ipython is added.
```